# Trying to print the factorial of a number as (5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x1 =120) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the factorial of a number using recursion by printing like this:

```
5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1=120
```

I just want this `(5 X 4 x 3 x 2 x 1)` part. I am trying a list comprehension, but not able to join with the "x" sign.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)

n=(int(input()))
print(([i for i in range(n,0,-1)]),"=",factorial(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print((" X ".join(str(i) for i in range(n, 0, -1))), "=", factorial(n))
```

output:

```
5 X 4 X 3 X 2 X 1 = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

`.join()` will help.

```
def factorial(n):
        if n==0 or n==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return n*factorial(n-1)

n=(int(input()))
list1=[str(i) for i in range(n,0,-1)]
print(" x ".join(list1),"=",factorial(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `join`. If you have a list of strings `integers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`, you can obtain the string `"1 X 2 X 3 X 4 X 5"` with the expression `" X ".join(integers)`.

To answer your exact problem the following code works:

```
n=(int(input()))
print(" X ".join([str(i) for i in range(n,0,-1)]),"=",factorial(n))
```

note the `str(i)` part, `join` would not work with a list of integers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible recursive solution (just one line, but you need Python 3.8+):

```
print((f := lambda n: f'{n} x {f(n - 1)}' if n > 1 else n)(n), '=', factorial(n))
```